# how to convert int into time period

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have today date and i want to reduce hours\days from it. i get the "hours to reduce interval" in int that indicate number of days.

I tried something like this:

```
    $today_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $temp_interval_date = $settings->days_back;

    $interval_date =  date('H',$temp_interval_date*24);

    $final =  $temp_interval_date - $interval_date;
```

My final goal is to get todaydate - interval period in this format

> 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

I am c# dude :)
Thanks

Comment: So are there always 24 hours in a day?

Comment: what actually you want? i am not getting the question.

Comment: Look at [datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects, particularly the [modify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) and [diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) methods, and at [dateinterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and its [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method

Comment: Today date - interval period = Some date,  
i want the "Some date"

Comment: @user2706762 so you're only interested in parts of the world that don't have any daylight savings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking but I *think* this is what you're looking for.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DatePeriod('P'.$settings->days_back.'D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

You can also do (if you're using PHP 5.2)

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-' . $settings->days_back . ' days'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

**reference**

- [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [`DatePeriod()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could be helpful:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', date('Y-m-d') ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it

```
<?php
$temp_interval_date = 2; //in hours (for example =2)
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-'.($temp_interval_date*24).' hours',strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
?>
```